# Retrofit dynamic HTTP methods

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm planning to replace Apache HTTP client with retrofit in my project.
The problem I'm facing is that retrofit didn't(I couldn't find) support setting HTTP method to request at runtime.
In my Web Service I don't know what HTTP method to call in advance, so annotations @GET, @POST, ... are useless.

Comment: what about to create 4 methods getDynUrl, postDynUrl, putDynUrl, deleteDynUrl

Comment: For more flexible configs you should use HttpClient, not RestClient

Comment: Thank you for response.
I want to specify the method (GET, POST, DELETE .. ) to request. I don't know the 'method' in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrofit is not designed for dynamic url requests. You configure retrofit with your API base URL then make specific requests.

For a more flexible dynamic option use out [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). It is the HTTP Client used by Retrofit and it easy to work with.

Comment: I think the question is about specifying the methods for dynamic requests, not about executing the requests.

Comment: Retrofit is not designed for dynamic requests, I will updated my answer to clerify.

Comment: Using OkHttp and using AsyncTasks are two separate issues. I use RxJava for the majority of my scheduling (use Retrofit & OkHttp on some projects).

Comment: Thank you cyroxis.
Yes I understand that OkHttp and using AsyncTasks are different issues. I chose Retrofit because callbacks are executed in UI thread and networking is done in background thread and there is no need using Asynctasks or Handlers.

Comment: That can be solved using RxJava, allows you to easily offload the work to a background thread received the results on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you.
I will use OkHttp + RxJava

Answer (score 2):

You can use Retrofit 2 for dynamic URL request with the new @Url annotation:

```
public interface CarService {  
    @GET
    public Call<ImageResponse> getPicture(@Url String url);
}
```

Then just also create @POST, @PUT etc. You are going to have to make the choice somewhere.