# How to pass Method type like POST, GET in retrofit dynamically in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
@GET
fun getAccountInfo(
    @Url url: String, @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>?
): Call<AccountInfoModel.Response>
```

How to pass this get method dynamically instead of declaring static

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544722/retrofit-dynamic-http-methods

Comment: @silentsudo how to pass in ok http ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic http methods in retrofit.
You can use okhttp for this to achieve please find my answer below

```
package in.silentsudo.test;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import okhttp3.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class OkHttpMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        final String host = "https://reqres.in/";

        System.out.println(get(host + "api/users/1", client));


        JsonObject postBody = new JsonObject();
        postBody.addProperty("name", "morpheus");
        postBody.addProperty("job", "leader");

        System.out.println(post(host + "api/users", postBody.toString(), client));
    }

    static String get(String url, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }

    static String post(String url, String json, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException {
        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }
}
```

OkHttp Reference: https://github.com/square/okhttp

Answer (score 0):

You can  add custom HTTP request method type (like GET, POST, etc). Please find below answer to understand it.

#### Kotlin

```
interface RetrofitService {

    @HTTP(method = "CUSTOM_TYPE", path = "custom/urlwithendpoint/")
    fun methodName() : Call<RequestBody>

    // if you want to call with a request body
    @HTTP(method = "CUSTOM_TYPE", path = "custom/urlwithendpoint/", hasBody = true)
    fun methodName(@Body params: RequestBody) : Call<RequestBody>

}
```

#### JAVA

```
interface RetrofitService {

    @HTTP(method = "CUSTOM_TYPE", path = "custom/urlwithendpoint/")
    Call<RequestBody> methodName();

    // if you want to call with a request body
    @HTTP(method = "CUSTOM_TYPE", path = "custom/urlwithendpoint/", hasBody = true)
    Call<RequestBody> methodName(@Body RequestBody params);

}
```

Comment: How I can pass GET or POST method to RetrofitService.methodName() and then make request with one of GET/POST method to backend dinamically? Any sample of usage?

Comment: You can replace CUSTOM_TYPE with any method name like GET/POST/PUT or any custom name like COUNT etc on it for request method.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't get me. I mean dynamically from other classes by call RetrofitService.getInstance().methodName(), how I can pass "POST" or "GET" to one particular methodName() with POST method and same methodName() with GET method?