# How to pass http method type dynamically to retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a method which can be used dynamically for all type of requests say, POST,GET and all others.

I have implemented a method like this

```
 @HTTP(method = "{method}", path = "{url}")
    fun callAPIs(
        @Path(value = "method") httpMethod: String,
        @Header("Authorization") auth: String,
        @Header("app-version") app_version: String,
        @Body data: JsonObject,
        @Url url: String
    ): Call<JsonElement>
```

But I am getting error. Can anyone help me solve this error?

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.myapplication, PID: 17793
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "{url}" does not contain "{method}". (parameter #1)
        for method APICallInterface.callAPIs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546082/4491971

> Retrofit is not designed for dynamic url requests. You configure retrofit with your API base URL then make specific requests.
> For a more flexible dynamic option use out OkHttp. It is the HTTP Client used by Retrofit and it easy to work with.

Comment: when I pass this   @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "{url}", hasBody = true) then it works then why it is not working for other methods?

Comment: Use okhttp. it will suit your needs. Retrofit is just a "wrapper" around okhttp.